# Avoiding Circular reference in Excel

Tags: excel, circular-reference

In Excel I have these columns

[image: Excel screenshot]

These are 2 loans. When either loan is overpaid i want to (dynamically) move the surplus over to the other loan. I can't seem to figure out how to do this while avoiding a circular reference.

most relevant cells:

```
H5 =IF(AND(G5<0;C5>0;-G5<C5);G5)
C5 =C4+A5+B5
```

Is it possible to do this and avoid a circular reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-arrange your sheet like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Formulas used:

```
B4 =E3+A4
C4 =-I4
D4 =IF(AND(B4<0,G4>0),MIN(-B4,G4),0)
E4 =SUM(B4:D4)
G4 =J3+F4
H4 =-D4
I4 =IF(AND(G4<0,B4>0),MIN(-G4,B4),0)
J4 =SUM(G4:I4)
```